# How to fix a gap between AppBarlayout and TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I'm trying to use a AppBarLayout with Toolbar a TabLayout component and a Viewpager, but I'm getting a black gap between toolbar and tablayout, and not really sure why. I've taken a look some examples of here and they don't work.

I put an image of my problem.

[image]

XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/home_appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/margin_8"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="@dimen/margin_8"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:paddingStart="0dp"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleMarginStart="@dimen/margin_8">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="toolbar"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/rosa_apelucy">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/grey"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/pink"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/pink"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE QUESTION**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blanco">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/margin_8"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="@dimen/margin_8"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:paddingStart="0dp"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleMarginStart="@dimen/margin_8">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="toolbar"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/gris_oscuro"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/rosa_apelucy"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/rosa_apelucy"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_25"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be a good practice-design in my view. You used `CoordinatorLayout` and `TabLayout` inside it and so much more issues.

Instead, use `CoordinatorLayout` as the root layout and after `AppBarLayout` as it's child, then `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` inside `AppBarLayout`.

So, the structure will be:

```
<CoordinatorLayout
  <AppBarLayout
   <Toolbar/>
    <TabLayout/> 
  </AppBarLayout>
   <ViewPager/>
<CoordinatorLayout/>
```

After that, use `ViewPager` inside `CoordinatorLayout` like this and add the following line of code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

**Update:** Support library:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="toolbar" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Working layout (AndroidX)

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="toolbar" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If he keeps this RelativeLayout with the black background he can do what ever he want he always will have this black 25dp height line in is view.

Comment: Is not the problem. I've remove it and persist the gap

Comment: @MaikPeschutter The `ViewPager` will not work properly if he/she use it like that. Actually, mentioned the right way to do that.

Comment: @S.P. I didn't exactly say "remove it", the problem is in the base design in your codes. Please take a look at my answer again. The way you designed it, doesn't seem to be correct. Gave you the best way to achieve such layout actually.

Comment: I've tried, but not show the toolbar and don't show the tablayout. Please check me update question with your code

Comment: Still visible the black gap and I can see other white gap below

Comment: Check my updated answer. Added for both Support library and AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@color/black">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This part is not the problem... I remove and still the gap is there